# SQL Syntax Error Multiple Counts

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

I'm having a problem with executing an SQL Query. This is what I do:

```
$sql = "SELECT
          SUM(PB = 1) AS PB,
          SUM(PG = 1) AS PG,
          SUM(PA = 1) AS PA,
          SUM(`Last Date Modified` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
            AS LastDateModified,
        FROM `psttodo-uit`";

$result = $app['db']->executeQuery($sql);

$count = $result->fetchAll();
```

Without the rule

> SUM(`Last Date Modified` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) AS LastDateModified,

it works. What's wrong with this rule?

This is my error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `psttodo-uit`' at line 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `,` before `FROM` statement

```
$sql = "SELECT
        SUM(PB = 1) AS PB,
        SUM(PG = 1) AS PG,
        SUM(PA = 1) AS PA,
        SUM(`Last Date Modified` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) AS LastDateModified
        FROM `psttodo-uit`";
```